# need help postgresql crosstab query

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, crosstab

I have two simple queries as following, which I fetch theme as two record(1 column) from PostgreSQL.

```
select count(*) from root.str
union all
select count(*) from back.str0
```

which returns something like this:

```
+===+
|103|
+===+
|98 |
+===+
```

But I'd like to have something like this:

```
+===+===+
|103|98 |
+===+===+
```

I've tried this, but Postgres raises error at `crosstab()` function and says the function is not exist.

```
select * from crosstab(
   'select count(*) from root.str
    union all
    select count(*) from back.str0'::text) as (int r,int e)
```

Comment: Which version of postgresql are you using?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson it's 9.2.1 bro

Comment: Then I suspect you've not installed the `tablefunc` module...? I can't remember from the top of my head how to do it, but I suspect there are answers on how to do it if you search the site.

Comment: `create extension tablefunc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you would need the crosstab module for that:

```
select (select count(*) from root.str) as str_count,
       (select count(*) from back.str0) as str0_count;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the [additional module tablefunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html) which provides the `crosstab()` function.

Consider this related answer with instructions and more advice:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

Also, what @a_horse wrote ...

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately crosstab functions only accepts physical available tables, it doesn't find temporary or alias selects(`with`).

Comment: @user2889419: A **CTE** (`WITH` clause) is only visible in the scope of the query it is attached to, so it has to be part of the query string passed to `crosstab()`. **Temporary tables** are visible in the current session and work just fine with `crosstab()`!